# Collect all values from uniq ids and pass them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm having trouble with JS and how to correctly collect and pass all values from a text field and hidden field on a button click.

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="add_109_01000340002001010_id" name="add_109_01000340002001010[id]" type="hidden" value="113000674">

<input add_type_code="109" autocomplete="off" autocomplete_key="109" id="add_109_01000340002001010_name" name="add_109_01000340002001010[name]" onkeyup="fillFlatNumber(this)" size="3" style="height: 10px" type="text" class="ac_input">


<input autocomplete="off" id="add_109_01000340002001009_id" name="add_109_01000340002001009[id]" type="hidden" value="112000674">

<input add_type_code="109" autocomplete="off" autocomplete_key="109" id="add_109_01000340002001009_name" name="add_109_01000340002001009[name]" onkeyup="fillFlatNumber(this)" size="3" style="height: 10px" type="text" class="ac_input">


<input autocomplete="off" id="add_109_01000340002001021_id" name="add_109_01000340002001021[id]" type="hidden" value="11405181">

<input add_type_code="109" autocomplete="off" autocomplete_key="109" id="add_109_01000340002001021_name" name="add_109_01000340002001021[name]" onkeyup="fillFlatNumber(this)" size="3" style="height: 10px" type="text" class="ac_input">
```

Those are text fields and hidden fields with unique ids. They are 'connected'. When you change the value in the text field, the value in the hidden field changes automatically.

When you click on a button, then values that will be written in the text field should be processed in js

```
function room_group() {
    $('.add').bind('click', function() {
        var hidden_values = 'something here' // Let's get all values here and pass them to the get request
        var values = 'something here' // Let's get all values here and pass them to the get request

        $.post('/link/definition', {
                val: values,
                hidden_val: hidden_values

            },
            function(response) {
                location.reload();
            }
        );
    });
}
```

The question is how to collect all of those values correctly? Unfortunately, I have no idea...

Comment: All id's must be unique. If not, your code is incorrect. And, `add_type_code` and `autocomplete_key` are invalid attributes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You mean ids of hidden and text field?

Comment: **Any** `id` may not be repeated within a web page. They are meant to always be unique. It doesn't matter what kind of element they are used on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to format your values.
You can serialize the values by searching for them with an appropriate selector and then you can create a JSON string as value.

```js
var hiddenValues = JSON.stringify($("input[type='hidden']").serializeArray());

var textValues = JSON.stringify($("input[type='text']").serializeArray());

console.log(hiddenValues);
console.log(textValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="h1" name="hidden1" />
<input type="hidden" value="h2" name="hidden2" />
<input type="text"   value="t1" name="text1" />
<input type="text"   value="t2" name="text2" />
```

Your POST will be something similar to:

```
var hiddenValues = JSON.stringify($("input[type='hidden']").serializeArray());
var textValues = JSON.stringify($("input[type='text']").serializeArray());

$.post('/link/definition', {
    val: textValues,
    hidden_val: hiddenValues
    },
    function(response) {
        location.reload();
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, but 1 thing, on a page, are some more hidden fields that should be not included, so is there any to collect?

Comment: The important phrase in my answer was: "with an appropriate selector". I don't have all your HTML to tell you which is the best selector to use, but you can add a specific class for each input you want to group. Ex: `<input class="hiddenTxt">` and as selector `$("input.hiddenTxt")`. Here is a good list of possible selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp